# react native createbottomtabnavigator hide tab bar label

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I need to know how to hide the bottom label.

I've tried the following:

> tabBarShowLabels: 'hidden', tabbarlabelvisible: false.

I also removed the `tabbarlabel: 'Home'` and it still shows

Any help would be appreciated or if someone could point me to the right direction.

[image]

```
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'


const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator ({
  Home:{
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintcolor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-home" size={24}  />
      )
    }
  },
  Inbox:{screen: Inbox,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-mail" size={24} />
      )
    }
  },
  Search:{screen: Search,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-search" size={24} />
      )
    }
  },
  Favorites:{screen: Favorites,
    navigationOptions:{ 
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
      <Icon name="ios-heart" size={24} />
    )
  }
  },
  Settings:{screen: Settings,
    navigationOptions:{ 
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-settings" size={24} />
      )
    }
  }

}
});



export default class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return <Tabs />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to define `showLabel: false` as the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#showlabel) says, just as

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator ({
  Home:{
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintcolor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-home" size={24}  />
      )
    }
  },
  ...
  ,
  Settings:{screen: Settings,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-settings" size={24} />
      )
    }
  }

}
}, {
  tabBarOptions: { showLabel: false }
});
```

Comment: thanks it worked could you please suggest how can we show the name only selected tab except selected tab other tab name will be hide

Answer (score 14):

On the new versions of React Navigation, you just need to pass `showLabel` prop as `false`

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{ showLabel: false }}>
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answer is perfect, But it messed the brackets a bit. So for a new bee like me, Here is the proper code.

```
const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: SettingsScreen
});
ProfileStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      title={'Profile'}
      name={focused ? 'tabIcon' : 'tabIconFocused'}
    />
  ),
  tabBarOptions: { showLabel: false }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

compatible with v6

```
 <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={() => ({
      tabBarShowLabel: false,
      ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **tabBarShowLabel** property

```
tabBarShowLabel: false,
```

Code

```
<NavigationContainer>

 <BottomTab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    activeTintColor: '#000',
    inactiveTintColor: '#fff',
    tabBarActiveTintColor: 'black',
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    
     //this one
    tabBarShowLabel: false,
  }
    <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <Icon
              name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'}
              size={24}
              color={focused && 'black'}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    ----
    ----
 </BottomTab.Navigator>

</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

for react-navigation v4, set the labeled property to false to display only the icons.

```
    const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator ({
  Home:{
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintcolor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-home" size={24}  />
      )
    }
  },
  ...
  ,
  Settings:{screen: Settings,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintcolor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-settings" size={24} />
      )
    }
  }

}
}, {labeled:false});
```